# How can I ensure my .net API only listens to requests from certain ip addresses?

Tags: .net, api, swagger

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins, policy =>
    {
        policy.WithOrigins();
    });
});

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
```

The above does not seem to work be I can still access the Swagger API calls from any IP address. I am new to c# and this technology so I am lost in how to lock down my API securely.

Comment: CORS has nothing to do with IP addresses.

Comment: IP filtering is best done at the webserver level, not within application code, unless you have a compelling reason to. What webserver are you hosting to host/front your application code?

Comment: I am using cloud run on GCP I am struggling to figure it out on the Cloud Run Level

Comment: Create list of IPs somewhere and in .Net Create filter so you can get IP Address of clinet with HttpRequest. ServerVariables

Comment: You can read up on how to create our own whitelisting middleware [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/ip-safelist?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Answer (score -3):

Try This

```
 builder.Services.AddCors(opt =>
                     {
                         opt.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", policy =>
                        {
                            policy.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().WithOrigins("**Your IP address**");
                        });
                     });
```